# Best way to handle multiple windows Qt4 python

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

I have got two main-windows which will run all the time and open other windows. Every window has to communicate with each other. All windows are created with qt designer and as I read in another question I should not modify these files, so I tried to make a new class (communicator) to handle all the jobs.
What is the best way to structure a project like this. So how can i communicate best between these windows now, e.g. if I press a button in 'self.mainWindows_images' I want to do something in 'self.mainWindows_classifier'

```
from classifier import Form as Form_classifier
from cnn_avg import Form as Form_cnn_avg
from images import Form as Form_images
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys


class Communicator():
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        self.mainWindow_images = Form_images()
        self.mainWindow_images.show()

        self.mainWindow_classifier = Form_classifier()
        self.mainWindow_classifier.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('cleanlooks')
    comm = Communicator()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

One of the window files, generated by Qt Designer, looks like with the additional -w flag:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
    Form.resize(1145, 654)
    ...

class Form(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, f=QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags()):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent, f)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

I want to do something like this and add the setImage-method to the mainWindow_classifier, becaus as I mentioned I should not modify the generated qt python file:

```
    self.mainWindow_classifier.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.setImage)

    def setImage(self):
            # change QLabel in self.mainWindow_images
```

Comment: Create instances of the PyQt objects that you can edit. For example, `class Communicator(QMainWindow)` would create an instance of `QMainWindow` that you can edit freely